# Add style from props to existing component styles in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I have the following component defined:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, View, Text } from 'react-native';

export default class Button extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.onPress}>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Text
            style={{
              color: this.props.foregroundColor,
            }}
          >
            {this.props.title}
          </Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    paddingTop: 15,
    paddingBottom: 15,
    paddingRight: 20,
    paddingLeft: 20
  },
});
```

I'd like to pass a prop `backgroundColor` to this component. But how do I extend the current `styles.container` to dynamically set `backgroundColor`? I've tried

```
<View style={
    ...styles.container, 
    backgroundColor: this.props.backgroundColor
}>...
```

But I get a `SyntaxError` when I do that...

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Do it like this way:

```
<View style={[styles.container, {backgroundColor: this.props.backgroundColor}]}>
```

React native will use StyleSheet.flatten to combine two object to be one style instance.

This is the same:

```
const newStyle = StyleSheet.flatten([
    styles.container,
    {backgroundColor: this.props.backgroundColor},
]);
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much :)

Comment: I am glad it helps. @Tiwaz89

Answer (score 0):

Basically, React native use an object for the stylesheet.

To fix the above error just add {} in styles.

like this.

```
<View style={{
    ...styles.container, 
    backgroundColor: this.props.backgroundColor
}}>
```

For understanding purposes, the first bracket is used for evaluation
and a second bracket is a stylesheet object that returns to the component. now you're spreading an object (container styles) inside the main object so now it merges with the styles you provided.